# Which KeyStore implementations can be used for storing symmetric keys?

Tags: java, keystore, symmetric-key

`java.security.KeyStore` uses `KeyStoreSpi` implementations to provide keystores of different types. Basic OpenJDK comes with support of JKS, JCEKS and PKCS12 keystore types. The first two implement proprietary Sun/Oracle format and PKCS12 is a public standard.

I know that JCEKS does support symmetric keys and PKCS12 does not. Which other `KeyStoreSpi` implementations (like Bouncy Castle) provide support of symmetric keys? It looks like devs like to hide such info. E.g. Bouncy Castle [docs](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) only mentions:

> The fourth is the BCFKS key store which is a FIPS compliant key store
> which is also designed for general key storage and based on ASN.1.
> This key store type is encrypted and supports the use of SCRYPT and
> the storage of some symmetric key types.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that a PKCS#12 keystore does not save secret keys in general? I'm working on Desktop OpenJDK 11.x and I do not have any problem in saving and reloading of a secret key with a PKCS#12 keystore.

But you are right - there are some Java implementations where this won't work - just give it a try!

output:

```
Keystore Type PKCS12
source: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1420427307-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----PKCS12
create a keystore
load the keystore and store a secret key
key after generation length: 32 data: eb6b8efafcee46880ea75b83754442efe4ee9d66ce755698cc803fd7775e4e78
load secret key from keystore
key after loading    length: 32 data: eb6b8efafcee46880ea75b83754442efe4ee9d66ce755698cc803fd7775e4e78
```

**Security warning: the code does not have any exception handling and is for educational purpose only.**

code:

```java
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class KeystoreTypePKCS12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Keystore Type PKCS12");
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677544/which-keystore-implementations-can-be-used-for-storing-symmetric-keys
        System.out.println("source: https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1420427307-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----PKCS12");    
        System.out.println("create a keystore");
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            try (FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("keystore.p12") {
                keyStore.store(outStream, "password".toCharArray());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("load the keystore and store a secret key");
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("keystore.p12")) {
                keyStore.load(inStream, "password".toCharArray());
            }
            // generate an aes secret key
            KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGen.init(256);
            Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
            System.out.println("key after generation length: " + key.getEncoded().length
                    + " data: " + bytesToHex(key.getEncoded()));
            // store it in the keystore
            keyStore.setKeyEntry("secret", key, "password".toCharArray(), null);
            // save the keystore
            try (FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("keystore.p12")) {
                keyStore.store(outStream, "password".toCharArray());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("load secret key from keystore");
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("keystore.p12")) {
                keyStore.load(inputStream, "password".toCharArray());
            }
            Key keyLoad = keyStore.getKey("secret", "password".toCharArray());
            System.out.println("key after loading    length: " + keyLoad.getEncoded().length
                    + " data: " + bytesToHex(keyLoad.getEncoded()));
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I did some unit tests and it appears you're correct and  PKCS12 is able to store at least AES keys. I'm using ChaCha20 and PKCS12 fails with `Key protection algorithm not found: unrecognized algorithm name: ChaCha20`. In opposite, JCEKS can store both AES and ChaCha20 keys. Still, symmetric key is basically just a byte array, don't understand why keystores should be so picky.

Comment: I'm glad to read that your tests run successfully. Could you kindly mark my answer as "accepted" - thanks?